# simple dom class selector

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors, innerhtml, getelementsbyclassname

```
<ul>
  <li> <div class="time"> at 2011-02-05 17:44:28</div></li>
  <li> <div class="time"> at 2011-02-05 17:40:20</div></li>
  <li> <div class="time"> at 2011-02-05 17:15:11</div></li>
  <li> <div class="time"> at 2011-02-05 17:04:14</div></li>
  <li> <div class="time"> at 2011-02-05 15:54:56</div></li>
</ul>

//Reformat timeStamps
var timeIndex = 0;
while (timeIndex < 51)
{
  var timeIndexHTML = document.getElementsByClassName("time")[timeIndex].innerHTML;
  timeIndexHTML = "Reformatted time";
  document.getElementsByClassName("time")[timeIndex].innerHTML = timeIndexHTML;
  timeIndex++;
}
```

How can I detect the last element of a class, and then make 51 a variable?

```
//
//*****************************EDITS HERE**************************************
//
//Example:
  var LAST_ELEMENT_OF_CLASS = someMagicCode("time");
```

and then

```
while (timeIndex < LAST_ELEMENT_OF_CLASS +1){...}
```

Note it currently doesn't work because it tries to evaluate

```
document.getElementsByClassName("time")[5]
```

Which doesn't exist

Comment: what does "then make 51 a variable" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me guess. What you want is this:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("time");
for(var timeIndex = 0; timeIndex < elems.length; ++timeIndex)
{
  elems[timeIndex].innerHTML = "Reformatted time";
}
```

(if that's not what you want please clarify question)